# Function within an Array in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel

I'm trying to use the following array formula to identify people performing above average during their prior 2 months:

```
SUM(IF((AVERAGE('Tenure_Sales Calcs'!I$2:I$1089,'Tenure_Sales Calcs'!J$2:J$1089)>C94)*('Tenure_Sales Calcs'!AF$2:AF$1089=$B41),1,0))
```

Columns I & J reflect `sales (-1)` and `sales (-2)` respectively. C94 is the average during that lookback period for all reps. Column AF is just a tenure criteria to organize the results.

It seems when I try to perform the AVERAGE function within the array condition, the entire formula fails. Was curious how to make this work.

Comment: Your formula syntax isn't correct. It's always difficult to work out the intent from a non-functioning formula - can you explain in words exactly what you want the formula to do?

Comment: I'm trying to count/sum how many times the average of (I2,J2) through (I1089,J1089) is greater than C94, with AF representing an additional criteria to be met. So for the avg(I2,J2),avg(I3,J3)...(I1089,J1089), how many times is it greater than C94. Let me know if that clarifies my question

Comment: OK, I think I understand that - I posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be with:

> ('Tenure_Sales Calcs'!AF$2:AF$1089=$B41)

If I try inputting that into a cell by itself I get an error. If I replace that segment of your original formula with an arbitrary value then your formula works. I'm not sure what you are trying to do with that segment. If you are doing another true/false test then you should try:

```
SUM( IF( (AVERAGE('Tenure_Sales Calcs'!I$2:I$1089,'Tenure_Sales Calcs'!J$2:J$1089)>C94)* IF(AVERAGE('Tenure_Sales Calcs'!AF$2:AF$1089)==$B41,1,0),1,0   ) )
```

Also, from your original formula it appears that there is no need for the SUM function at the beginning since the if statement returns a single value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the cells you need to average in columns `I` and `J` will always be populated, in which case to get the average of the two ranges it's sufficient to add them and divide by 2, so you can use this formula:

`=SUMPRODUCT((('Tenure_Sales Calcs'!I$2:I$1089+Tenure_Sales Calcs'!J$2:J$1089)/2>C94)*('Tenure_Sales Calcs'!AF$2:AF$1089=$B41))`

That will give you a count of rows where the average of columns `I` and `J` exceeds `C94` and also where `column AF` = `B41`